# RadAjaxManager won't update radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a radgrid which should update when a checkboxlist is changed(achieved on a on selected event which is triggered by AutoPostBack) however when I check a checkbox in the list the RadAjaxLoading picture will work correctly to display the loading image over where the RadGrid is however it will never go away and re-display the grid. According to console errors in my web browser, I keep getting a error of:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_destroyTree'**

This is how i've set up my manager if it helps at all:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManagerNotesView" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGridNotes">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridNotes" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="CheckBoxListCategories">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridNotes" 
                    LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Can anybody help me solve this error? The RadGrid will never be re-displayed as of current

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the error to be an incompatibility with .NET 4.0 and an old version of telerik(2009) managed to get around the error by using the following patch in a separate JavaScript file and including it in the footer of my master page.

http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/203221_default.zip

Answer (score 3):

This script solved my problem:

```
function _destroyTree2(element) {
    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
        var childNodes = element.childNodes;
        for (var i = childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var node = childNodes[i];
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                if (node.dispose && typeof (node.dispose) === "function") {
                    node.dispose();
                }
                else if (node.control && typeof (node.control.dispose) === "function") {
                    node.control.dispose();
                }
                var behaviors = Sys.UI.Behavior.getBehaviors(node);
                for (var j = behaviors.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    behaviors[j].dispose();
                }
                this._destroyTree(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._destroyTree = _destroyTree2
```

Put it on the end of the page.